# How do I fix this ERROR 13 in my Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I created a Firebase cloud function to encrypt the password in Firestore using Google Cloud KMS. But I am still getting ERROR 13 when I test the cloud function. My network connect to Cloud KMS is fine and I'm pretty sure the request message isn't too large. Do you have any ideas what the problem could be.

Here is the cloud function:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const {KeyManagementServiceClient} = require("@google-cloud/kms");

const locationId = "europe-west1";
// const projectId = "my-project-id";
const keyring = "my-keyring-name";
const key = "my-key-name";
const client = new KeyManagementServiceClient();

/**
 * Encrypts a plaintext string using Cloud KMS.

 * @param {string} plaintext The plaintext string to encrypt.

 * @return {Promise<string>} A promise that resolves to encrypted ciphertext.
 */
async function encryptPassword(plaintext) {
  const request = {
    name: client.keyRingPath(locationId, keyring, key),
    plaintext: plaintext,
  };

  const response = await client.encrypt(request);
  return response.ciphertext;
}

exports.passwordAdded = functions.firestore.document("/accounts/{documentId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      const account = snapshot.data();

      // Encrypt the hashedPassword field.
      const password = await encryptPassword(account.hashedPassword);

      // Update document with encrypted password
      await snapshot.ref.update({hashedPassword: password});
      return Promise.resolve();
    });
```

Here is the error:

```
  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: passwordAdded.
✔  functions[us-central1-passwordAdded]: firestore function initialized.
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-passwordAdded"
⚠  functions: Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: invalid encoding
    at callErrorFromStatus (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:99:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:32)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
    at /home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/build/src/v1/key_management_service_client.js:240:29
    at /home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
    at repeat (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:80:25)
    at /home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:118:13
    at OngoingCallPromise.call (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/call.js:67:27)
    at NormalApiCaller.call (/home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/normalApiCaller.js:34:19)
    at /home/leonard/Projects/password-manager/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/kms/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/createApiCall.js:84:30
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
i  Request to function failed: Error: socket hang up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the encoding of `plaintext`?

It seems that `grpc-js` cannot serialize your request message failing with "invalid encoding" error.